# AngularJS project configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make my first AngularJS project. I'm having problems with the project configuration. First i created a Java project AngularJSExample. Then I converted it to AngularJS project.I have configured script paths for Tern projects. The hello.html doesn't know what is greeting. Can you please tell me why?

These are my files:

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller='HelloController'>
<p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>



var myController = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myController.controller('HelloController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting ={
            text : 'Hello'
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This didn't help. I have this in my console: Tern request#angular_type: {"query":{"type":"angular","subtype":"type","angularTypes":["module"],"expressio‌​n":"myApp","scope":{},"files":["projectFolders/js/controllers.js"]}} {"type":"Module","name":"myApp","origin":"projectFolders/js/controllers.js","ang‌​ularType":"module","module":"myApp"} Tern response#angular_type with 23ms: Tern request#angular_type: {"query":{"type":"angular","subtype":"type","angularTypes":["controller"],"expre‌​ssion":"HelloController","scope":{"module":"myApp"},"files":["projectFolders/js/c‌​ontrollers.js"]}}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the current stable version of AngularJS, 1.2.25, you need to add the app name to the `ng-app` directive. So, your markup must be:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

[Working JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/qatenihunaca/1/edit)

Comment: This didn't help. I have this in my console:

Tern request#angular_type:

{"query":{"type":"angular","subtype":"type","angularTypes":["module"],"expression":"myApp","scope":{},"files":["projectFolders/js/controllers.js"]}}

{"type":"Module","name":"myApp","origin":"projectFolders/js/controllers.js","angularType":"module","module":"myApp"}

Tern response#angular_type with 23ms:

Tern request#angular_type: {"query":{"type":"angular","subtype":"type","angularTypes":["controller"],"expression":"HelloController","scope":{"module":"myApp"},"files":["projectFolders/js/controllers.js"]}}

Comment: I just took your code and put it into JSBin then added `myApp` to `ng-app`, and it works in the sample. If you don't see "Hello, World!" you must have other errors somewhere. By the way, that stuff you have in console doesn't looks like an error.

Comment: This is how my hello.html file looks like when I open it with a browser. {{greeting.text}}, World

Comment: check your inclusions: angular.js and controllers.js. Are the path correct?

Comment: I have a project that is called AngularJSExample. It has a src folder, JRESystemLibrary and a folder which I created, it is called   projectFolders. In my projectFolders I have a html and a js folder. Html folder contains a hello.html file and js folder contains controllers.js. I have configured in project properties tern Script path. It is a folder named js - AngularJSExample/projectFolders and has a controllers.js. And I removed <script src="angular.js"></script>. Now I have <script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js">
</script>.

Comment: Considering what you said, the path to `controllers.js` specified in `hello.html` should be `../js/controllers.js`, and not just `controllers.js` as you wrote. This file should contain the JavaScript code you posted in your question.

Comment: This is my code now. It is not working. <hml ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller='HelloController'>
<p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
</div>
</body>
</html> And this is not working <script src="AngularJSExample/projectFolders/js/controllers.js"></script>.

Comment: I wrote `../js/controllers.js`, **not** `/js/controllers.js`. Please check thoroughly your code and avoid extended discussions in comments. Do some testing on your code, I assure you that the code works, as you can see in the JS Bin example (which you should learn to use as well as your browser inspector/developer tools). Yours is a simple path issue.

Comment: But this is also not working, <script src="../js/controllers.js"></script>

Comment: Well then, I can't help you anymore, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

This question is about [AngularJS Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse).

At first, your script must be included inside script element. I have tested with this HTML file :

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller='HelloController'>
<p>{{greeting.text}}, World</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>


<script>
var myController = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myController.controller('HelloController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting ={
            text : 'Hello'
    };
}]);
</script>
```

and everything works well :

- completion on module, controller, expression (greeting)
- hover on module, controller, expression (greeting)

I think your problem is about Ctrl+Space inside expression. You must see HTML elements <a>, <abr>, and greeting is on the bottom of the completion. To change this order, please read 
[HTML Angular Tag Proposals](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/New-and-Noteworthy-0.5.0#user-content-html-angular-tag-proposals)

Comment: Ok, tnx, do you maybe know why I got this in my console Nodejs Commnand: "D:\eclipse-jee-luna\plugins\tern.eclipse.ide.server.nodejs.embed.win32.win32.x86_64_0.5.0.201409012129\node-v0.10.22-win32-x86_64\node.exe" "D:\eclipse-jee-luna\plugins\tern.core_0.5.0.201409012129\node_modules\tern\bin\tern" --no-port-file
Project dir: D:\AngularJSWorkspace\AngularJSExample
null
Why null?